# how to share folder between host os and docker container

Tags: docker

I have created a volume of a docker image. The docker image is:

```
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow   latest-gpu          7f09e75cdc12        4 months ago        1.289 GB
```

And the container volume is:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                     COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS  
e99c80d2d53e        gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu   "/run_jupyter.sh"   21 hours ago        Up 11 minutes             6006/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp   deep
```

I need to share a folder between the host `Ubuntu 16.04` OS and the docker container.
I ran this command for doing this:

> docker run -v /home/cortana/deep-learning/:/home gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu

This didnt lead to the folder being loaded into the container `deep`. I dont know what to do after this and am really new to the container stuff in docker. Please explain your answer a bit too.

EDIT:
I deleted the container and then ran these commands:

```
docker run -v /home/cortana/deep-learning/:/home gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu
nvidia-docker run -p 8888:8888 --name deep gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu
nvidia-docker exec -it deep bash
```

There is no folder called `deep-learning` in the `/home/` folder in the container. What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API I'm aware of to change the mounted volumes on a running container. You destroy the existing container (`docker stop` and `docker rm`) and create a new one with the proper configuration (`docker run`). If you find yourself trying to maintain a single container, upgrading apps inside the container or with data inside, odds are good that you're trying to recreate a VM rather than isolating a process, which is an anti-pattern.

---

From your edit, you didn't create the /home/deep-learning folder, you created the /home folder. You also appear to be creating a second container named deep without any volume mounts and exec'ing into that one. To make a container with the /home/deep-learning volume mount and the name deep, run it like:

```
docker run -v /home/cortana/deep-learning:/home/deep-learning \
  -p 8888:8888 --name deep gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu
```

Comment: I dont know much about docker or virtualization. I just want to use the tensorflow library that I installed using docker and want to use a GUI based editor to edit files in the docker container. What do you suggest I should be doing?

Comment: I've updated my question with a response to your edit.